# How to zoom paused ARFaceTrackingSession

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I think the title is self-explanatory. I am starting a session like this:

```
let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

Then I add some nodes to the scene.
Then I pause the scene:

```
self.sceneView.session.pause()
```

Then, I want to programmatically zoom into the face so that the screen is filled with the face.

But I cannot figure out how. I have tried

```
let cameraNode = sceneView.pointOfView!
faceNode.simdScale = cameraNode.simdWorldFront * 1
```

But that does not seem to take any effect.
I can do it with CGAffinTransform on the SceneView itself but that approach seems wrong.

Comment: What have you tried? If you show us some of the code you already have, as well as your attempts, it'll be easier for us to help you.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Updated the Q with what I have tried and what I know.